# Group by first column and turn second column into column names and third as its values

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

Assuming df is this

```
    date        code    value
0   2007-04-02  0001    12
1   2007-04-02  0002    23
2   2007-04-02  0003    51
3   2007-04-02  0005    18
...
```

Would like to obtain the following, which is grouped by the date, but the code column will turn into the column names of the new df

```
    date        0001    0002    0003    0004
0   2007-04-02  12      23      51      18
1   2007-04-03  21      1       19      47
..
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df = df.set_index(['date', 'code']).squeeze().unstack().reset_index()
```